# retrieving a value from a jquery countdown/up back to the controller in asp.net mvc2

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to measure the time the user spends on a page before clicking submit. I am using the jquery countdown in a hidden div.

I want that when the user clicks submit, the value of the countdown will return back to the controller, what is the correct way of doing this?

in my form I have a hidden input:

and the script:

```
$(function () {
 $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ since: 0,onTick: setSeconds, format: 'S'});
});
```

function setSeconds() {
     $('response').**text**($('#defaultCountdown').countdown('getTimes')[6]);
 }

in the controller I use

```
ed.responseTime = Int32.Parse(collection["response"]);
```

I tried to swap text with html and it doesn't work either

is it because the page is model based and the hidden input is not in the model?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the entire answer, but I believe you need to use .val() to set the hidden fields value.  Also $('response') doesn't look like a correct selector.  Is 'response' the id?  If so use $('#response').

For retrieving the value on the server-side, try using Request["theName"] or just add it as a second parameter in your method signature.